# jQuery DataTables: Multiple checkbox filtering

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter, datatables

I'm using jQuery datatables just to display some data, but know, i want to filtering those with multiple checkboxes.
My table contains this header:  `Host, Type, Record, Description, Free`
And these are my checkboxes outside of the datatable:
**Type**: `MX` `A` `CNAME`
**Free**: `0` `1`
So at the begining I want to show all of the data. If someone now checks the checkbox `MX`, it should only show data with type `MX`. If someone checks `MX`, `CNAME` and `0`, it should only show data with these filters. You know what I mean?
I've a plugins which can do this, but the checkboxes are under the columns, my checkboxes are outside the datatable.

Any idea?

Comment: Before I start: Are you using server sided processing on this? If not, can you prepare a plunker?

Comment: @mainguy No, i'm not using server sided processing. What is a plunker?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use this function:

```
function filterme() {
  //build a regex filter string with an or(|) condition
  var types = $('input:checkbox[name="type"]:checked').map(function() {
    return '^' + this.value + '\$';
  }).get().join('|');
  //filter in column 0, with an regex, no smart filtering, no inputbox,not case sensitive
  otable.fnFilter(types, 0, true, false, false, false);

  //build a filter string with an or(|) condition
  var frees = $('input:checkbox[name="free"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join('|');
  //now filter in column 2, with no regex, no smart filtering, no inputbox,not case sensitive
  otable.fnFilter(frees, 2, false, false, false, false);
}
```

Look at the comments to see what it does.

Call it from your html like this:

```
  <input onchange="filterme()" type="checkbox" name="free" value="0">0
  <input onchange="filterme()" type="checkbox" name="free" value="1">1
```

Plunker is a testbed for HTML and JS Snippets that greatly helps others to understand where your issue is located and to give a fast response on how to fix things. It simply works like html/js/css editor that renders your example on every keypress and is awesome.

[Click here to see how I fixed your issue with Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b8cLVaVlbNKOQhDwI2mw?p=preview)

On the left side of the Plunker you will find the files I used in the process (index.html and script.js)

While this works and should give you an idea on how to continue, you should think about using radio buttons for the FREE filter, because it would make more sense.

Since this is a quiet complicated issue come back to me if something needs more explanation.

Comment: I have problems with the `free`. I got data under record which contain `0` or `1`, so he shows them up too.

Comment: What do you mean? 0 and 1 are covered by the two inputs. As I said, it would make more sense here to use either two radios which have either Free/Not Free or a single checkbox which returns Free True/Free Not True. Is that what you want? In the current setup checkmarks can be on both values 0 and 1 which will of course return all records.

Comment: Look at this Plunker which uses radio buttons, which are more logical: http://plnkr.co/edit/45hOwYG13VAooKfPPAw3?p=preview

Comment: Uh, now I understand. Then you should filter frees in the respective column only. In my example is used 2 as filter column which is the record column in your code. Limit to row 4 (starting count at zero) in this line: otable.fnFilter(frees, 4, false, false, false, false);

Comment: Now look at this last plunker which should match your data structure: http://plnkr.co/edit/gDQHtg7y3XyqN8InCiwI?p=preview Are you beginning to see how useful plunkers are?

Comment: For free i only need one checkbox actually(0 or 1) and i've changed the column to 4.. but it still filters the rest of the column too.

Comment: I did this: `<input onchange="filterme()" type="checkbox" name="free"> Free`  AND  `frees = ($('input:checkbox[name="free"]').is(':checked')) ? "1" : "0"; oTable.fnFilter(frees, 4, false, false, false, false);`

Comment: Not a good idea, since this way no one can see ALL of the entries. I like the radio approach more. Anyhow: http://plnkr.co/edit/urEIpx0prGu9ksqD2xix?p=preview does what you want. For further Information: Use my plunker as a base to make changes and when you are stuck click on FORK. See how the URL changes? Copy the URL and add it to your post. This way you save me some work:-)

Comment: thanks for sharing, I wanted jQuery data-table having multiple checkbox filter as a dropdown for TH (title). This works for me, thanks once again :)